# Is there an SD Card diagnostic utility?

Tags: usb, software-recommendation, sd-card

Are there any SD Card diagnostic utility programs out there for Ubuntu? I would like to run tests on my SD card to check capacity, write speed etc. I have one for windows but I am looking for a Linux flavor and hope to find some source code.

Answer (score 16):

Look for `Disk Utility` on you dash (as an option press Alt+F2 and type `palimpsest`)

[image]

Click on the disk you want information from, to test it click on `Benchmark`

[image]

To start benchmark, select `Read only` or `Read/Write` benchmark

[image]

Comment: "disk utility" is the nice title for `palimpsest`

Comment: Hey, there are screenshots! Cant miss those! :)

Comment: On a german ubuntu - like mine - looking for "disk utility" does not yield any results.

Comment: fair enough, solved.

Comment: On 13.04 (raring) palimpsest was replaced with gnome-disks ("Disks" when you access it from the menu). The instructions are the same as posted by Bruno Pereira.

Comment: @cweiske: Look for „Laufwerke“

Answer (score 16):

## For Ubuntu 13.04 and later...

---

### From the dash

[image: Find <code>disks</code> in the launcher]

### From the command line

```
gnome-disks
```

---

## Usage

Select the disk you wish to test.
[image]
Find the menu in the top right and select *Benchmark...*

[image]

A window will appear. Click *Start Benchmark...* to see:
[image]

I left the defaults and clicked *Start Benchmarking...*. It will run for a while, building the chart over time.
[image]
You can see that my new SD card's read rate is around 7 MB/s, while the write rate is only slightly over 2 MB/s.

The model shown here is a SanDisk Ultra SDXC with an advertised speed of up to 30 MB/s. As you can see, [the transfer rate is not as advertised](https://askubuntu.com/q/481956/17164).

Answer (score 7):

### Reported Capacity

```
$ df -h /media/sdcard
```

### Real capacity and write speed

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/sdcard/testfile bs=10M
1xx+0 records in 1xx+0 records out 9xx bytes (9.4 GiB) copied, 34.xx seconds, 271 MB/s
```

`dd` will fill up all the space. Remove the `testfile` afterwards.

Comment: What if his sd card is only 1Gb???

Comment: `df` will reveal the capacity reported by the SD card, but that may not be the true capacity. `dd if=/dev/null` does nothing because `/dev/null` is always empty. I think you mean `dd if=/dev/zero`.

Comment: Or `cat /dev/zero > /media/sdcard/testfile`

Answer (score 4):

There is also [`f3`](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/) ([Repository](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3), [doc](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)), that specifically aims at detecting fraudulent cards (f3 stands for "fight flash fraud").

It was [suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35727/how-can-i-check-the-condition-of-an-sd-card) first.